# explanation about UrlMappings in grails3

Tags: grails, groovy, grails3

I don't understand this code in UrlMappings.groovy

```
"/*/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"            
constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
```

I searched google already but still don't understand what does the code do. 
Can someone tell me what is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4-seconds search brings up a page like http://docs.grails.org/3.1.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings.

In short, the code inside `UrlMappings` is processed by UrlMappingBuilder and has the following meaning:

It maps anything (wildcard `*`) after the 2nd `/` to a `$controller` and `$action` with some object's `$id` and a specific optional `$format`.

Examples could be:

```
/blah/some/action
/blah2/some/action/42
/halb/some/action/42.json
```

I wouldn't accept a mapping like that, as it can be very ambiguous.